# Are questions regarding Hindu astrology allowed here?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Indian astrology has its base in Hinduism. But are questions relating to that considered on-topic here?

Comment: It should be on-topic, why should we keep our science outside?

Comment: Should not be off-topic...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my opinion, **yes**, Hindu astrology should be on topic. Astrology is deeply intertwined with many other aspects of Hindu ritual practice, and to arbitrarily separate out this particular aspect would make little sense.

Comment: One thing I would like mention here is, Astrology is a **wide** subject. Let's restrict ourselves to Hindu astrology and let's avoid comparisons and questions such as, "this logic says this, but hinduism says this, what is right"...

Comment: Joythisha is one of the six vedhanga other five are niruktha, vyakharana, Chanda's, shiksha and