# Where is the Hinduism SE FAQ?

Tags: support, status-completed

As a new user of any site I first have a look at the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) of the site. I could not find the FAQ for this site containing the rules and regulations of this particular site (like what questions we can ask here and so on).

Can anybody please guide me to the FAQs of this community?

Comment: @sv. Meta answer are determined by votes, no need to delete anything. Just downvote what is not applicable and upvote which is fine.

Comment: @sv. To clarify more on what our new mod just said, I am looking for something like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq). It will be seen like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jXXED.png) on the front page of http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes, I figured out the FAQ tag (and already provided a link to SO's FAQ tag in my earlier comment) and your intent in asking for it. Good idea!

Comment: @sv. Yep. Also regarding a single answer, there are many posts with more than one answer. The way it is decided is, if there are subquestions in the question, each and every subquestion is added as a new answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma You might find a few insights to help you here [When and how do mature \[faq-proposed\] posts graduate to \[faq\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316468)

Comment: will surely look into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), refer [FAQ Index for Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277)

---

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag has been added to below mentioned question:

- [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version)
- [Political questions and Scientific questions will be considered off-topic  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-questions-and-scientific-questions-will-be-considered-off-topic)
- [Citing Wikipedia  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/citing-wikipedia)
- [Guidelines for new users for answering questions  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-for-answering-questions)
- [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se)
- [Users asking for scientific answers / reasons  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/users-asking-for-scientific-answers-reasons)
- [What are the allowed languages for questions, comments or answers here?  **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-are-the-allowed-languages-for-questions-comments-or-answers-here)
- [Are questions regarding Hindu astrology allowed here? **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/are-questions-regarding-hindu-astrology-allowed-here)
- [How much of Ayurveda is accepted here? **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/2995)
- [Please use consistent spelling in your posts **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/please-use-consistent-spelling-in-your-posts)
- [Are mythological TV shows going to be counted as source? **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/are-mythological-shows-going-to-be-counted-as-source)
- [Explain abbreviations used by users briefly **✓**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/explain-abbreviations-used-by-users-briefly)

---

<sub>**Note**: This answer is a community wiki answer, So feel free to present you suggestion in it, without the check mark, we will surely look into it.</sub>

Comment: What is "As of" at the beginning supposed to mean? @Paṇḍyā