# FAQ Index for Hinduism Stack Exchange

Tags: support, faq, search

## Community FAQ

---

**For Hinduism Stack Exchange and Hinduism Meta Stack Exchange**

For official guidance from Stack Exchange, visit the [Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help).

Hinduism.SE is part of a wider network; for issues that apply to Stack Exchange sites in general, see the **[FAQ list on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)**.

### Asking Questions

- [Political questions and Scientific questions will be considered off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-questions-and-scientific-questions-will-be-considered-off-topic)
- [Are questions regarding Hindu astrology allowed here?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/are-questions-regarding-hindu-astrology-allowed-here)
- [Users asking for scientific answers / reasons](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/users-asking-for-scientific-answers-reasons)
- [Should we close questions related to Sanskrit language and grammar as off-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/748/)
- [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/)

### Guidelines

- [Guidelines for new users for answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-for-answering-questions)
- [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se)
- [Please use consistent spelling in your posts](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/please-use-consistent-spelling-in-your-posts)
- [Guidelines for when to use “Chat” instead of “Comment”](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/1049)
- [Chatroom guidelines](https://hinduismsechat.github.io/)

### Sources and citations

- [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version)
- [Official policy for deleting answers that don't cite sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/) (should be read with updates mentioned in the answer)
- [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/)
  Also visit [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/816/)
- [Citing Wikipedia](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/citing-wikipedia) (More Recent Version: [Issue of answers citing poor sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2320/277))
- [Are mythological TV shows going to be counted as source?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/are-mythological-shows-going-to-be-counted-as-source)
- [Is Personal Experience a Source?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/266/)

### Others

- [What are the allowed languages for questions, comments or answers here?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-are-the-allowed-languages-for-questions-comments-or-answers-here)
- [How much of Ayurveda is accepted here?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/2995)
- [Explain abbreviations used by users briefly](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/explain-abbreviations-used-by-users-briefly)
- [Concerns about brigading](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/5212)

### Is your question not part of the FAQ?

First look at questions tagged [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to see if there is a question not in this index that might have the answer you seek. If you still can't find an answer, then see the following instructions for proposing an FAQ question.

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body.
  The answer goes in an answer.
- **Link back** to this index. Paste this at the end of the question:

  `[Return to FAQ index](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478)`
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems
  to have hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet
  community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
- After the post has the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag added to it, add a link in the above [table of contents](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478).