# Can we post our own translations as answers if none are available?

Tags: discussion

In reference to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19812/what-is-meaning-of-the-maruti-stotra-composed-by-ramdas-swami), there is no English translation available for the stotra anywhere on the internet.

Most of the "English" translations are actually transliterations. Like [here](http://www.prophet666.com/2010/08/maruti-stotra-english-marathi.html)

Since I happen to know the native language I can translate the verses with the help of [this PDF](http://www.samarthramdas400.in/literature/bhimrupi.pdf) that has explained the stotra in Marathi.

My question is: **Would that be allowed as an answer?** Since I really don't have a valid source except for that PDF, and the translation would be my own and all translations are like a double edged sword they have many possible variations.

**Bottomline: Are personal translations allowed as answers if there are none other sources available? For any language?**

Comment: There's two separate issues: 1. When you cite a Sanskrit (or other language) quote in your answer, are you allowed to provide your own translation rather than using an existing translation?  2.  When someone asks a question requesting a translation of a Sanskrit quote, can you provide your own translation as an answer?  I think the answer to the first question is definitely yes.  As to the second question, it depends on what the OP is looking for.  If they're just asking for the meaning, then I think it's fine to provide the meaning yourself.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can provide your own translation but take care it is free of errors. 2. Translation questions of a Sankrit (or any language) quotes, is off-topic. Only interpretations or meanings are allowed. If they are related to Hinduism. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/should-we-close-questions-related-to-sanskrit-language-and-grammar-as-off-topic) meta post.

Comment: If it is from Sanskrit to English how can one be sure of the fact if the translation is correct or not? If its from ur mother tongue to English then it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, everyone! :) I wasn't sure if my answer would be allowed which is why I thought it better to ask this question first, than remain in doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always recommended to cite sources for the interpretation. However, if there is no reliable work available, **Yes**, you can provide your translations and meanings.

But it's recommended to have a good knowledge of languages you're translating e.g Marathi and English. You can also go through some dictionary which can help to do better interpretation or translation.

It would be better if you **provide the reference** (for example [this](http://sanskritdocuments.org/marathi/ebooks/BhimarupiMarutiStotra.pdf) ebook in your case) based on which you're writing your translation/meanings.

The work is available on sanskritdocuments.org under the [Marathi religious texts](http://sanskritdocuments.org/marathi/index.html#Dharmic) section:

[image: resource]