# Should a moderator with extreme bias be removed as moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, specific-question

Both of below posts attempts to denigrate a widely worshiped Hindu God in the guise of a question:

- [Which scripture does Pillai Lokacharya reference in which Shiva enjoins his devotees to offer human sacrifice?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27087/which-scripture-does-pillai-lokacharya-reference-in-which-shiva-enjoins-his-devo)
- [What scriptures describe Shiva discussing selling salt in the Banasura story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27071/what-scriptures-describe-shiva-discussing-selling-salt-in-the-banasura-story)

The evidence that the moderator is making collective posts in collaboration with a poster is strong.

Who can remove a moderator's privileges and how can I petition them?

Comment: You have raised a strong point which was raised earliar by moonstar and me.

Comment: But nothing EVER happens @Rakesh Joshi - the above two examples are very regrettable and lower the quality of the board seriously.  This poster is running a board within the board - a board pertaining to his sect and he has a circle around him that doles out upvotes and downvotes like automatons to further his cause.

Comment: What is the evidence that the moderator is making collective collaboration with another post? The quoted part in the first post is an excerpt of the second post. One user asked from it. It is a quite common thing that one question gives rise to other question. It is not surprising that Keshav's post was on the main page. Also, what do you mean by "collaboration"? Do you suggest sock puppets? What's the problem with the sect of user?

Comment: It is silly to look at the mods with sectarian and personal beliefs. When you are opposing moderator, oppose his actions as a moderator. Not his personal beliefs or user activity. Your edit proves another point too. Only sect members not belonging to mod's sect are opposing him. Can we say like that? I know you won't agree. Bottom line is don't see mods from sect or belief point of view. Oppose in moderation only. Otherwise, they are also users. They also ask questions and write answers.

Answer (score 13):

I'm a [Community Manager here at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do). During the beta period, we are responsible for appointing moderators and we also have the ability to remove them, if needed. (This is actually [quite rare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269728/1438).)

I'm currently looking at some tickets (sent via [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact)) we got from users in the last few days. I don't think we need to remove any moderators right at the moment. Before we get to that point, I think there needs to be a community agreement about how to deal with sectarianism. It feels like there are disagreements about what should and should not be allowed. This isn't unique to Hinduism, by the way. This same issue has been seen on [Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site) and, to a lesser degree, [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians).

I'm currently looking at those tickets and reading up on Hinduism (I'm almost entirely ignorant) to get an idea of who divisions manifest. I'm also looking at [your excellent FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) to understand how you all have addressed these issues in the past. When I feel like I have a basic understanding, I'll post my thoughts as an outsider and community manager here on meta.

In summary, it's not going to do much good to remove a moderator if we don't get to the heart of the issue: how should this site handle sectarian disagreements.

Comment: But several users has raised such issues against the moderator. You can go through those related meta posts too.

Comment: The only moderator who is indulging biases consistently is @TheDestroyer - His moderation of comments and posts ultimately subverts views different from his own. When asked why, he replies saying that comments were flagged and hence removed - On further probing, it is apparent that he blindly accepts these rude/abusive indications just because they are proposed by a certain clique who hate the Vaishnava sect. Additionally, the user SK (OP) who keeps inciting the main with his divisive questions targeted against what he proclaims is a 'minority' sect. He's a self-proclaimed Anti-Vaishnava.

Comment: There is a clear double standard in the "Anti-Vaishnavas" - If a question is about Vishnu - they are weirdly comfortable with questions that are denigrating statements and are silent on its propriety. Whereas, they pick up spears and go to war if even a well-researched question on Shiva, that is even the slightest bit controversial in their eyes, is posted. Apart all this, they have the gall to claim that they are being neutral. On top of this, they parade that one portion of Vedantic belief - Advaita is the defacto standard for answers which when opposed can be ostracising to say the least.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Come with the proofs & examples. Everyone can claim anything. You are claiming the things without any proofs or instances.

Comment: @Rohit. Please tell me how to access deleted comments.

Comment: Like SK and others (moonstar) collected examples against Keshav, better if you also could collect for the same for the destroyer, Can you? Otherwise it's just a claim without any ground evidences. But they collected against Keshav instead of talking about delete etc how you couldn't? Btw, I will abstain commenting on CM's answer. Don't wanna send so many notifications. @LakshmiNarayanan

Comment: @Rohit. Do you understand my statements regarding the destroyer? How do I show evidence of deleted comments without access to them? In any case, here is a [related discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/conversation/regarding-deleting-comments)

Comment: evidence of Advaita supremacy tendencies by OP: [Example1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44066051#44066051); evidence of Vaishnava Hate by OP: [Example2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44066151#44066151). There are more like this.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan You included my name??. Those comments (with no proper references) were flagged by community users because you were literally posting same comment on every question to prove Shiva is subservient to Vishnu (the Supreme God for your sect). Posting same  comment on every post even though not related is spam. Remember "You shall promote no God" from Guidelines.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Out of my curiosity, Why did you bring this up now ? ^^

Comment: Yes, the site has a great FAQ index. The problem arises when it is not known to everyone and not followed by everyone.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, since OP has set precedent of naming Mods, I'm merely following. My comments from relevant question were removed where I had to repost again for example see [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/what-are-some-popular-names-of-vishnu-which-are-also-the-names-of-shiva-in-the-s#comment76821_26840)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I brought this type of behaviour being practised in the meta earlier [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-to-handle-attacks-by-propagandist-users)

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I don't want to discuss on this further.  CMs can see deleted comments by me and they can decide on their own whether it was proper or not. You were literally posting same comment on every questions and many such comments were flagged.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Support all your claims please. On which question that I posted to was it irrelevant?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan No need to prove here as they can see from my profile or your profile. let them decide whether it was fair or unfair.

Comment: All evidence points to the issue being intricately tied to the user who is also a moderator. Removing their mod privileges is the first step to addressing the issue. I am convinced, and I am sure many on the site will agree, that the issue was fostered and festered by this one user and will very likely disappear with the user.

Comment: I would also like your opinion on the wisdom behind retaining a mod even in the face of longstanding, repeated, opposition against them and dissatisfaction about their performance by a considerable number of the community users. Every now and then there is an uprising of sorts against this mod (by different users) and it quiets down because nothing comes out of it. I hope your intervention this time means things will change for the better. It is also my opinion that the mod in question is using SE as a political platform to push his sectarian agenda ,starting from relentlessly 1/2

Comment: Hammering away that Vedanta is uttara mimamsa. Vedanta for the longest time has come to be synonymous with upanishad which are the climactic portion of the Veda. However most upanishad propound the concept of nirguna Brahman which is in opposition to the mod's sectarian beliefs. I believe he is playing the long game of trying to change the definitions, obscure long held notions (that dont suit his agenda),. 2/3

Comment: undermine the value if certain historical figures(whose philosophies are in opposition to his sect's) even though such figures are recognized worldwide as philosophical geniuses ,poets extraordinare, unparalelled in devotion and unbiased and truly compassionate towards humankind. I went rather descriptive here to impress the mod's bias and lack of objectivity . 3/3

Comment: To Jon, Please don't be biased by moonstar's outrageous claims that advaita is the default perspective of vedanta - this is precisely the kind of propaganda i'm warning against. Nobody denies that Upanishads also talk of Nirguna Brahman, it is the interpretation of different schools that is in often the source of argumentation - this is unavoidable on a forum discussing religion; Also, Newton was a genius, but there's no denying that Einstein sets (as far as science of today is concerned) the record straight - this doesn't mean that one is denigrating Newton - it is a similar situation here.

Comment: Comments are not for complaints and compliments to current mods. Please use "Contact us" for complaints. Sit back and relax if you have no problems with the moderation team.  Have a good day.

Comment: @moonstar Are we having a philosophical talk on what most upanishad preach here? Nirguna Brahman is not accepted by all. If someone belonging to a sect posts questions about their sect, is that a political agenda? How? Is this not a site to ask questions about different sects? What is the necessity of accepting what the world is talking about philosophical geniuses? It depends on the person what to accept.We should not force popular beliefs on all. What do the mod's sectarian belief to do with this issue? If you are opposing mod, keep it within moderation only. Not personal beliefs.

Comment: No @Sarvabhouma we are not having a philosophical talk about what the upanishads preach. I know that nirguna brahman is not accepted by all. What I am trying to articulate here is the deliberate , repeated and subversive attempts by the user in question to change the connotation of the term vedanta to refer to uttara mimamsa because his beliefs align with uttara mimamsa. Vedanta is a larger umbrella term and often specifically used to refer to the upanishads, by its very definition veda + anta (end portions of the veda = upanishad).

Comment: My claims as Lakshminarayanan professes seem outrageous only to one who is not very educated in scripture  Regardless, Jon is not the arbiter of the philosophical impasse.

Comment: Your ad hominem attacks will not yield fruit - Don't try to confuse people by creating distinctions without a difference - Uttara Mimamsa and Vedanta are the same.

Comment: @moonstar What do you think Uttara Mimamsa is if not Vedanta?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Why is it so difficult to understand what I am saying. Or is this another deliberate attempt to subvert? I am saying Vedanta is not ONLY uttara mimamsa. Vedanta is much larger , includes atma vidya and originally means upanishad. Saying vedanta is uttara mimamsa is a very limited and latter-day definition being used conveniently by the user. The term Vedanta is more synonymous with upanishad than with uttara mimamsa and my contention is that this does not sit well with the user in question.

Comment: Uneducated arguments will not receive counter-arguments from me. Enjoy.

Comment: @moonstar Uttara Mimamsa is synonymous with Vedanta and Upanishads (all 3 are synonymous with each other). Ramanujacharya and Shankaracharya state this. Uttara Mimamsa refers to the jnana kanda of the Vedas whereas Purva Mimamsa refers to the karma kanda section of the Vedas.

Comment: @Ikshvaku the broader term includes bramha sutras as well which are vedanta sutra (plus loosely any work on atma vidya). the reason uttara mimamsa started being labelled as vedanta is because the term vedanta had become synonymous with advaita vedanta.  Anyways, I have stated my points. thank you for the discussion.

Comment: Hi @Jon , Is there any update on this ? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to see this infighting. For me it is silly to say that one Self is above another Self. First, we know from stories that Shiva and Vishnu love each other. Second, we know from philosophy that Shiva and Vishnu are both part of the same unified reality. If I hate my brother, I hate myself. Such is *adharma*  Perhaps, though, we can learn a valuable lesson from this situation

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto _et al_: I've started a discussion [on meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/moderating-for-knowledge-not-truth) about the issues I've seen so far. It's taken me longer than I thought to go through the tickets, but I'll begin answering them this afternoon.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī, although there is infighting, i must clarify that the reason for it is different than the common misconception that vaishnavites hate shiva. no, it's far from the case. they don't hate nor disrespect shiva the deity. they hate/disrespect the notion that any deity, is or can be, equal to vishnu. 'shiva'-dveshi is different from 'shiva=vishnu'-dveshi

Comment: @ram I don't understand what you mean. Brahman is Brahman. What is the point in arguing whether your elbow is holier than your knee? They are both part of the same being.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī, that again is your opinion. Vishnu is not a 'part of' Brahman like Shiva, Brahma or any other deities are. Vishnu = Brahman.

Comment: @Ram Okay, you can use those semantics, but nothing changes and I see no reason to get upset. If we can agree there is One and only One, then why fight over the label we of incomplete understanding call it.

Answer (score 5):

This is something next level work. Better confirm you really want to do it. Before escalating it to Higher ups, talk to the moderator. Try to sort out things if possible.

In any case you can reach to SE staffs or Community Managers. They're mostly reachable via email or Tavern room of Meta.SE chat.

Comment: If nobody besides me wants to remove this moderator, then its pointless.@heLittleNaruto

Comment: Well it is not, if you have proper evidence, A moderator is a user only at the end just with extra privilege. That's it.

Comment: Nobody besides you? Are u kidding? @SK