# Few questions on user suspensions

Tags: support, user-suspension

It must be an extremely disappointing feeling for a highly active and a fairly contributing user to find that he is banned for a period of 6 months or one year or more. Given that he will be eager to participate but he can't and for such a long period of time.

Probably he may not even feel like coming back after the ban period is over.

I understand that the ban reasons must be quite substantial in such cases and which of course are to be kept between the user and the moderator concerned.

Few questions:

- Suppose, the user feels that he was banned for wrong reasons. Can he complain to higher moderators right now. Or will he have to wait till the ban period is over?
- Were there instances where higher mods have actually reversed such a local mod's decision?
- What if he creates a new account now in an urge to participate again? What will be done to that new account? And what will be the effect of this new-account-creation on the original account when it's active yet again?

Comment: "Fairly contributing"? then he would not have been suspended.

Comment: Fairly contributing means highly contributing.. Isn't asking Qs the primary activity/contribution on the site for a user? @Pandya

Comment: Asking questions meant to be primarily divisive and provoke response which is what the banned user was trying to do is not contribution.

Comment: Questions about user suspensions is off-topic for meta. It is between the suspended user and the moderator. It is not our business. There is already a question on the site where the reasons are explained.

Comment: [This comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/should-a-moderator-with-extreme-bias-be-removed-as-moderator#comment5558_1294) would have possibly sped up the user's suspension.

Comment: Nothing, just the influence of [Srimannarayana Effect](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/why-is-hinduism-se-not-expanding) discovered by Srimannnayana K V.

Comment: @AnuragSingh That's surely working strong in the background.

Comment: Although ur comment there has got many upvotes but it does not make any sense at all.. Because a highly contributing user can also be banned if he is constantly violating the rules.. So being contributing is not a safeguard. @Pandya

Comment: Also if we are allowed to talk about that particular user then I have just now gone through his Qs.. He has got a staggering 216 Qs to his name and of which I will say more than 85% are very good ones and many of them have already been answered from scriptures.. So, he has surpassed many surely on the contribution part.. So it is not right to label him as just a "trouble maker" like some of u are trying to do here..@Pandya

Comment: And @Pandya if you think he was not contributing, then you can find several **'1'** reputation users on HSE who have not even asked a single question or answer. But the heap of those '1' reputation account is not being deleted

Comment: @AnuragSingh He was also the top user [for this month](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users) and he would have been probably topping too if he was not suspended. Needless to say one can not really achieve that feat without being a consistent contributor.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the specific question is not the questioner's business. If asked broadly about policies rather than a user, I would vote to leave open

Comment: @AnuragSingh We don't delete *nor suspend* 1-rep users just because they don't contribute. There's nothing wrong with users creating an account and forgetting them. Regardless of reputation, no one is immune to suspension (not even diamond mods!) when they break the rules.

Comment: If it's not my business to know then why do u find an answer being posted and that too my a mod of one of the SE sites? and BTW where do u see me talking about a particular user anywhere in the question? @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: Perhaps you and I use different grammar/vocabulary to talk about hypotheticals. To me the entire thing reads like it is about a single, specific, male person.

Comment: No it can be about any user.. do not come to any conclusion because of my use of he in the question.. you can not say it's about a particular user unless I link him or name him in my post.. @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: @Rickross Well, I *can* because that's exactly what you are saying in standard US English grammar (it's called implication). I admit a miscommunication. Please don't further complicate the issue by telling me how my native language can or cannot be interpreted.

Comment: You simply need to understand that if this did not deserve an answer then that Mod wouldn't have written one.. @RubelliteYakṣī

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Suppose, the user feels that he was banned for wrong reasons. Can he complain to higher moderators right now. Or will he have to wait till the ban period is over?

There are no higher mods. There's CMs and yes, you can use the contact us link.

> Were there instances where higher mods have actually reversed such a local mod's decision?

Not as far as I remember, and there's often a dialogue when these things come up. Its possible, but I'd think that overruling mods without a great reason and consultation would be a bad precedent. Mods do not take suspensions lightly. I quite often find the need to suspend a user who's been on my site a whole *painful*

On the other hand. a user on a longer suspension could have a word with the CMs, pinky swear to be better, and *be* better, and who knows, they could contributer.

> What if he creates a new account now in an urge to participate again? What will be done to that new account? And what will be the effect of this new-account-creation on the original account when it's active yet again?

When he's found out, the new account is deleted, and the old account suspended even longer. Lets just say, it is a *terrible* idea for someone to do that. It is a sure way to prove you're not willing to accept the rules of the site.